# Qt tab order keys

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtgui, qevent

A user can step through the widgets of QtGUI via key "Tab" or via arrow keys "<-" and "->".

Does anybody know how to disable the arrow keys for this purpose? I need the arrow keys for something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to reimplement the [corresponding event](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) in your own QWidget subclass as follows:

```
bool MyWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *keyEvent)
{
    if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Left || keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Right) {
        // Do nothing
    } else {
        QWidget::keyPressEvent(keyEvent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reimplement event() or keyPressEvent() / keyReleaseEvent() of main window. In reimplemented methods you can place your desired actions.

Answer (score 1):

I may use QAction for this purpose. So you wont need subclassing.

```
QTabBar *tabBar;
........................
QAction* pLeftArrowAction = new QAction(this);
pLeftArrowAction->setShortcut(Qt::Key_Left);
QAction* pRightArrowAction = new QAction(this);
pRightArrowAction->setShortcut(Qt::Key_Right);
tabBar->addActions(QList<QAction*>() << pLeftArrowAction << pRightArrowAction);
```